# Sybase numeric datatype and Python

Tags: python, sap-ase

I have encountered a problem that I can not figure out.

I'm working on an application written in Python and a Sybase ASE database using sybpydb to communicate with the datbase.
Now I need to update a post where one of the columns in the where clause is of numeric(10) data type.
When selecting the post Python treats the data as a float no problem there.
But when I try to update the post using the numeric value I just got from the select i get a "Invalid data type" error.

My first thought was to try to convert the float to an integer but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the actual SQL query text which is sent to the ASE server before conclusions can be drawn.